# Find $\angle ACB$ using the knowledge of cyclic quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, cyclic-groups

[image]

$O$ is the center of the circle

Find $\angle ACB$ It is given that $\angle ABD=50^\circ$ & $\angle ACD=50^\circ$ (*inscribed angle theorem*)

Can you help me here stating the reasons

Comment: Does $O$ belong to $\overline{BD}$?

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos  Yes $O$ is the center of the circle

Comment: There is no (unique) answer to the problem as posted. Please recheck the exact wording of the problem, and edit any missing information into the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the diagram did not properly show the relation between O and BD.

Comment: -1 to the OP for accepting an answer *without* editing his question to include the missing information, as asked twice. Voting to close as well, because the question as posted is incomplete, and the answer won't help anyone in the future who doesn't read the comments, first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that AOD = 100 (2*ABD since angle subtended at center is twice the angle subtended on the arc)

Hence AOB = 80 (since Points D O and B are collinear  )

Hence ACB =40 ( angle subtended at center is twice the angle subtended on the arc)

Ps- I am not yet familiar with Mathjax or latex :(
Note that ACB,AOB...are all angles

Comment: `Note that AOD = 100` Only if the center $O = AC \cap BD$ which is *not* stated in the question.

Comment: Yes ,I see your point .( But I guess that was what he meant). Now I see why you asked to edit any missing info .

Comment: Corrected,thanks.

Comment: @Futurologist `AOD=100 even when O lies on neither diagonal` That's (only) if you take $O$ to be the center of the circle (which was not specified in the original question, but edited in later). My previous comment assumed $O = AC \cap BD$ instead. In that case all that can be said is that $\widehat{AOD}=\frac{1}{2}(\overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{AD\,} + \overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{BC\,})=\frac{1}{2}(100 + \overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{BC\,})$ but $\overset{\mmlToken{mo}{⏜}}{BC\,}$ is not known and cannot be determined from the information provided. In either interpretation the question is incomplete.

Comment: @dxiv Then I apologize and I withdraw my correction. I saw that indeed the condition that $O$ is the center of the circle was added later so your comment was correct. It sucks when people write sloppy posts and this one is a particularly STUPID ONE.